# access trigger button in updatepanel inside a loginview?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

hi i am having problems with to define my trigger control in the ajax updatepanel. the button is inside a loginview now i wonder if this is possible to make the updatepanel to find that control somehow?

tried to search but did not find any info on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx) it doesn’t look like you can do this:

*"The control that the AsyncPostBackTrigger control references must be in the same naming container as the update panel for which it is a trigger. Triggers that are based on controls in other naming containers are not supported."*

The only thing I can suggest is to put the LoginView inside the UpdatePanel.

Comment: You can reference a naming container as a trigger. In that case, all child controls in the container that cause a postback are considered triggers for the UpdatePanel control

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rip for his answer, but you can reference a naming container as a trigger. In that case, all child controls in the container that cause a postback are considered triggers for the UpdatePanel control.

You can check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for this.